# Ruby: Why is my Code false?

Tags: ruby

Trying to multiply each number by array position, and it's coming out false:

```
def the_sum(number)
  i = 0 
  number = 0 
  ans = 0 

  while i < 0 
    ans = string[idx] * string.index
    i += idx
  end

  return ans  
end

test =

the_sum([2, 3]) == 3 # (2*0) + (3*1)

the_sum([2, 3, 5]) == 13 # (2*0) + (3*1) + (5*2)
```

and it comes out false?

Comment: Using Ruby methods another way `[2,3,5].map.with_index { |e,i|  e*i }.inject(:+)`

Comment: Don't put "solved" in the title or deface your post. Either close the question, or write/accept an answer instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems here

```
def the_sum(number)
  i = 0 
  number = 0 # You just cleared your input variable!
  ans = 0 

  while i < 0  # You previously i = 0 so this will never be true
    ans = string[idx] * string.index
    i += idx
  end

  return ans   # Ans is and was always 0
end
```

This can be fixed by calling `each_with_index` on the `Array` that you're passing.

```
def the_array_sum(array)
    ans = 0 

    array.each_with_index do |val, index|
      ans += val * index 
    end

    return ans
end

the_array_sum([2, 3]) == 3
# => true
the_array_sum([2, 3, 5]) == 13
# => true
```